# Set process priority on already running process batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

How do i change the priority of an already running posses i now that i can use this to start the posses: `START /HIGH notepad.exe` but how do i change it for an already running notepad. Thanks if any one can help with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [wmic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (WMI command-line):

```
wmic process where name="notepad.exe" CALL setpriority "high priority"
```

The priority can be "idle", "below normal", "normal", "above normal", "high priority", "realtime", or an integer value.

Integer values for priorities can be found on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be saying `Value map does not contain the input value for this property`

Comment: Did you include the quotation marks? They are required.

Comment: I have use an exact coppy of above.

Comment: It looks like "low" is no longer a valid priority string. I updated the answer.

Comment: Setting to realtime, always goes down to "High", is it possible to set realtime?

Comment: Setting to `Realtime` requires `SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege`. Try it with admin credentials.

Comment: will this work even on "cmd.exe" from batch? ...batch that will start that cmd.exe?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Instead of using "High" just use the integer value 128. So, your code would be `wmic process where name="notepad.exe" CALL setpriority 128`.

Here are all the priorities and their corresponding IDs:
256 = Realtime  |  128 = High  |  32768 = Above normal  |  32 = Normal  |  16384 = Below normal  |  64 = Low