# How to make a batch file run a program and then set priority higher?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, cpu, explorer

Hi I have seen a couple of questions like this but feel like I am missing something when I attempt to follow these instructions

>

> Create a .bat file to run the program, use a timeout command to wait a few seconds to let the secondary process run, then use the command below to change the secondary process priority to what you want.
>
> wmic process where name="process name" CALL setpriority "value"
>
> Possible values: "idle", "low", "below normal", "normal", "above normal", >"high priority", "realtime"

I have  made a batch file containing these lines:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\STAR WARS Battlefront\starwarsbattlefront.exe"  
timeout /t 60 /nobreak 
wmic process where name="starwarsbattlefront.exe" CALL setpriority "above normal"
```

When I run this I get an error. I have read a bunch of articles on StackoverFlow and SuperUser on this but none of them have made the final product clear. Sorry for seeming ignorant (cause I am) I feel like I am missing something obvious. Can anyone clear this up for me?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT *

The error is: *'C' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Comment: Edit your question to include the text of the error message, please.

Comment: Remove word `start` from your command; [`start` command considers that text in the first pair of double quotes is window title](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: Alternatively, add `""` right after your `start` command.

Comment: @JosefZ, I think removing `start` lets the batch script wait until the `*.exe` file quits, which is not the intention of the OP...

Comment: `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ … \starwarsbattlefront.exe"`. _SomethingDark_ and _aschipfl_ are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set process priority on already running process batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996307/set-process-priority-on-already-running-process-batch-file)

Answer (score 5):

```
::Launches Star Wars Battlefront and sets priority to "above normal"
@echo off

START /ABOVENORMAL /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\STAR WARS Battlefront\" "" "starwarsbattlefront.exe"
timeout /t 60 /nobreak
wmic process where name="starwarsbattlefront.exe" CALL setpriority "above normal"

echo Done.
TIMEOUT 10
exit
```

Better command to launch an application. With this you won't have any issues :]. The "/D" is basically "from directory". The line that starts with :: is just a comment. You won't see it when the .bat file is executed. The end part just shows the text "Done." and then has counts down from 5 to 0 before closing.

The /ABOVENORMAL might not work as intended because by starting the .exe you might be prompting Origin to start the application. So then the priority might not be applied to Star Wars Battlefront. That's why I left the "wmic" part in. It should work fine for other applications however.

There are probably even better and faster ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I write my scripts on my .bat files.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\STAR WARS Battlefront
START starwarsbattlefront.exe
WMIC process where name="starwarsbattlefront.exe" CALL setpriority "high"
EXIT
```

Comment: Please describe `WHY` you believe this works better than the OP's question.