# Change priority of an already running program

Tags: batch-file

I have a program named `RobloxPlayerBeta.exe` which is already running, and must be launched with a specific priority.

Is it possible from a batch script to change the priority of that running executable? and if so, how?

Comment: did you do a search or look at the suggestion list when asking this? [Set process priority on already running process batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23996307/995714), [How to make a batch file run a program and then set priority higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34116576/995714), [Set priority of active window using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37800247/995714)

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic process where name="Notepad.exe" call setpriority "Realtime"
```

Possible levels are Realtime , High, Above normal , Normal , Below normal, Low. You can use also numeric values.