# How to automatedly confine a batch file run on a single logical processor?

Tags: windows, multithreading, batch-file, single-threaded

I want to automatedly confine some (imagemagick image processing) batch jobs to run in the background on a single logical processor so as to minimize the impact on performance of other real time applications.

The method I have cobbled together is to use a command line argument as a flag.  When the batch file is first started with no command line argument (and no affinity) it will start itself again with affinity set to the last logical processor, adding a dummy argument to indicate the affinity has been set and to proceed with the main body of the batch job:

```
REM START OF THISBATCHFILE.CMD
IF NOT [%1]==[] GOTO AFFINITY_SET
SET LAST_PROCESSOR=1
FOR /L %%I IN (2,1,%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%) DO SET /A LAST_PROCESSOR*=2
PROCESSOR = %LAST_PROCESSOR%
START /B /AFFINITY %LAST_PROCESSOR% THISBATCHFILE.CMD DUMMY_ARGUMENT
EXIT 0
:AFFINITY_SET

REM Batch Job Starts Here
REM ImageMagick command 1
REM ImageMagick command 2
REM ...
REM ImageMagick command N
REM Batch Job Ends Here
EXIT 0
```

This seems to be working OK on my 4-core Win8.1 system to confine the batch jobs to the last (4th) logical processor.  My question is - is there a 'better' way to do this?

Comment: I doubt that the impact is minimised by affinity, it could make opposite effect, you should change priority instead.

Comment: @kan - that's a good idea, I can add or replace the start /affinity argument with a priority one like /belownormal.  Thanks!  I still have the same question on the implementation method..

Comment: For a CMD it looks ok... Probably you could start looking somewhere here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996307/set-process-priority-on-already-running-process-batch-file If you want better - just use Linux, he-he

Comment: @kan I tried /belownormal and /low (confirming in task manager the setting) but both still had significant impact on my real time app while /affinity 8 constraint worked as desired.  Problem is that my real time app (circa 2002) defaults to low priority and gets reset back to low even with start /high or manual task manager change.  So seems my first instinct to constrain affinity is useful for my case after all; a strange coincidence, for sure.

Comment: I managed to figure out my real time app priority issue - re-installing it did the trick.  Running my real time app in high priority with batch file priority lowered didn't help, unsurprisingly, it still suffered some ~10% performance hit .. BUT with batch file affinity constrained to one thread helped a lot, reducing the performance hit to <5%.  So, circling back, it seems the affinity constraint is useful for some cases, maybe generally so.

Comment: About the wmic alternative to set process affinity or priority, that method seems to be generic to all processes of the same name that could have the drawback of altering the affinity or priority of any other cmd.exe running, unless I'm not understanding the capability properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the resources ImageMagick uses in 3 different ways... via the command line as you start a process, via environment variables and via the config files. For your use case, I would suggest you use the environment variables which will be easier than changing every invocation of `convert` and more flexible than editing your system config files which would always throttle ImageMagick regardless of whether your real-time application is running.

You can see the resources that you can alter, and their current values, by running:

```
identify -list resource
```

**Output**

```
Resource limits:
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 17.18GP
  Memory: 8GiB
  Map: 16GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 192
  Thread: 1
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

I suspect you would want to reduce the number of threads (parallelism) and set a smallish amount of time to relinquish the CPU occasionally. You could also alter the memory ImageMagick is allowed to consume.

So, in concrete terms, I would try setting limits just prior to a bunch of ImageMagick commands:

```
...
...
SET MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1
SET MAGICK_THROTTLE=50

REM Batch Job Starts Here
REM ImageMagick command 1
REM ImageMagick command 2
REM ...
```

Alternatively, you can specify limits at each invocation of `convert` like this:

```
convert -limit thread 1 input.png ... <processing> ... output.png
```

If you look at the number of files in my initial limits list, you can see it is `192`. I can demonstrate what I am talking about by limiting the number files to `2` for the duration of a single command, and the command I use is one that lists the limits...

```
convert -limit file 2 -list resource info:

Resource limits:
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 17.18GP
  Memory: 8GiB
  Map: 16GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 2             <--- 2 files only
  Thread: 1
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

So, for the duration of the command that lists how many files I can have open, I have limited the number of open files to `2` and it shows that.

Comment: Thank for your detailed and clear answer.  I didn't realize that resources could be controlled through the imagemagick command line.  This solution could work for me with 2 significant drawbacks: a) my batch file would get significantly less readable inserting limit parameters to every invocation of convert, composite, etc and b) any other non-imagemagick commands issued from the batch file would need another solution.  For those reasons I still prefer my proposed method, at least for my usage.